# How to customize dialog with up arrow

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

I need to develop a dialog similar to the one in the image, and I don't know what is the best approach (I'm a newbie):

[image: Sample dialog]

Which approach do you consider to be the best?

Define one custom dialog and define the custom layout (up arrow) in some way?
Define one image with 9-patch and use it as an imageView with text inside?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, You need tooltips views not dialogs. Dialogs will not serve your purpose.

please refere below library

https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips